# How can I use dart ffi properly in a pub package?

Tags: dart, rust, dart-pub

I am currently building a console package with Dart, and Rust using FFI(foreign function interface). Since I can't/shouldn't publish dll/so/dylib files, how can I add a build functionality to it. With that functionality, the required files should be built after the package is downloaded, so that the interop-ed code can work properly. How can it be done? Will the user that downloaded the package need to have Rust in his machine to build the files?

Comment: FFI in which direction? Are you publishing a crate-lib usable by C-code? Or are you developing a Rust application?

Comment: For accessing the dart API simply add a dependency to the `dart` or `dart-sys` crate.

Comment: @A.Nilsson I'm creating a pub package for dart, not for Rust crate.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either distribute binaries or require the user to have a Rust compiler.

Comment: Thanks. I also just found out about https://github.com/dart-lang/tflite_native/tree/master/lib/src/blobs and I'll just distribute binaries like that.